# Complementoa1 numero binario python

Tags: python, string

estaba haciendo el complemento a1 en python para dos números binarios.
lo que no entiendo es porque si a num le pongo solo 0, el 1 me lo devuelve solo una vez y no en la cantidad de 0 que le puse, por ejemplo si yo le pongo 0000 me devuelve solo 1, y no 1111.
Lo estoy haciendo con strings, mi código es el siguiente:

```
def complementoa1(num,bits):
    string=str(num)
    nuevastring=""
    for elem in string:
        if elem=="0":
            elem="1"
            nuevastring=nuevastring+elem
            
        else:
            if elem=="1":
                elem="0"
                nuevastring=nuevastring+elem
    return(nuevastring)

print(complementoa1(0000,8))
```

Comment: Puedes combinar el `else if elem=="1"` como `elif elem=="1"`. Eso ayudará a que tu código no se vuelva un caos cuando más estructuras de control se unan a la fiesta. Por cierto, puedes escribir `nuevastring=nuevastring+elem` de forma más simple, `nuevastring += elem`.

Answer (score 1):

No existe el número `00000` como tal, pues existe solo el número `0`. y cuando pasas `00000` **Python** lo interpreta como simplemente `0`. Igualmente si pasaras. `01`, es el número `1` por lo tanto **python** lo interpreta como `1`

Lo que puedes hacer es pasarlo de una vez como `string` en lugar de transformarlo en la función, es decir.

```
print(complementoa1('0000',8))
```

En este caso al ser una cadena de texo, **python** la interpretará tal cuál está.